# Does auto-sharding in MongoDB work on shards with many small collections/small databases

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

In the MongoDB documentation for auto-sharding it says: "Sharding is performed on a per-collection basis. Small collections need not be sharded."

Our business has many databases (~100), with many small collections (~30), each with a document count of 1 - 3000. Our DB system is looking at approximately 100,000,000 page views per month.

In that scenario will sharding ever activate since the collections are never big enough even though the DB usage and site traffic is certainly high enough to require load balancing. From the docs I can't seem to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it makes sense to shard depends a little bit on whether you have mostly writes or reads to the database. Sharding is primarily used for write-scaling, but if you are not doing a lot of writes, then simply using replicasets with "slaveOkay" for the reads might work just as well.

From the numbers that you provided you seem to get about 9 million documents, but are they large documents? If they easily fit in memory, then there is most likely not even going to be a need for replicasets besides for failover capabilities.

Comment: In this scenario we are doing probably 9 : 1 read/write, so it appears that sharding is entirely unnecessary. I am investigating replica sets and whether they can provide us with the necessary and load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without knowing more about your use case, but I'll give it a shot.

Are you sure sharding is what you need?  What does your insert rate look like?

If you are going to have a static set of data, or even a relatively static set, then you probably don't need to shard, you could simply use more secondaries and enable slaveOK reads.  The reads will be distributed to the various secondaries and scale up your read capacity.

If that is not the case, and you do need to shard, then there are options.  But first, to explain briefly and at a high level how automatic sharding works:

The mongos process is responsible for splitting and migrating chunks in general.  These are two separate operations - splitting and balancing.

- Splits occur when the mongos sees that a certain portion of the
  maximum chunk size has been written, it initiates a split if there is
  in fact enough data to warrant it.  Over time, with enough data
  written, the number of chunks grows.
- Balancing occurs when there is an imbalance of chunks (currently 8 in
  2.0, though moving to a more dynamic heuristic in 2.2).  The balancer migrates the chunks around the shards until  a balance is achieved.

So, you need to be writing enough data relative to the max chunk size (default is 64MB in 2.0) to generate the chunks needed for the balancer to move them around appropriately.  If that is not going to happen with your data, then you can look at:

1. Decreasing the chunk size (has drawbacks too - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Administration#ShardingAdministration-ChunkSizeConsiderations)
2. Manually split/move the chunks

For the manual instructions see:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Splitting+Shard+Chunks

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Moving+Chunks